# Android ListView and Intents Issue

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I'm building a simple menu-driven app and my implementation of intents is giving me a few problems.

I have 3 menus. Menu1 needs to pass info to Menu2 and Menu2 needs to pass info from Menu1 and Menu2 to Menu3. For this I'm using Intents in this sense.

```
    String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

    // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountList.class);
    // sending data to new activity
    i.putExtra("product", product);
    startActivity(i);
```

This should pass the ListSelection to the next Activity i.e AccountList and AccountList passes the same to SingleListItem as below

```
    TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_label);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // getting attached intent data
    String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
    // displaying selected product name
    txtProduct.setText(product);
```

Now the above should display the ListSelection from AccountList but alas, it is not doing so. Any assistance you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try getIntent().getExtras().getString("product")

Answer (score 0):

Try call

`i.getExtras().getString("product");`

instead of

`i.getStringExtra("product");`